# The need for independence in random sums when using law of total expectation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_n : n\in \mathbb{N})$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Let $S_0 = 0$ and $S_n = \sum _{i=1}^{n}X_i$ for $n \geq 1$. Let $N$ be a non-negative integer-valued random variable.

The question I am working on asks to assume further that $N$ is independent of the random variables $X_i$, and to show that $\mathbb{E}(S_N)=\mu\mathbb{E}(N) $. I know how to show this in the standard way using total expectation, by conditioning on $N$:
\begin{align*}\mathbb{E}(S_N)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{E}(S_N|N=n)\mathbb{P}(N=n)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{E}(S_n)\mathbb{P}(N=n)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\mu \mathbb{P}(N=n) \\
&=  \mu\mathbb{E}(N). \end{align*}

My question is the following: Do we need $N$ to be independent of the random variables $X_i$ for the above argument to follow? I do not see where I used the independence of $N$ in the above working.

On trying to find an answer to this, I found the following [document](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-ST.pdf) concerning the proof of Wald's equation. In remark 1.2 on page 4, it talks about the case where the stopping time is independent as a special case, so it seems that independence is indeed important. I would like to understand why independence is needed.

Comment: Independence is useful for the second equality. You have that $\mathbb E[S_N\vert N=n]=\mathbb E[S_n\vert N=n]$, but the latter may not be equal to $\mathbb E[S_n]$ if $N$ is not independent of $S_n$.

Comment: Thanks @Will, that's what I was missing, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Will commented, you need independence for the step $\mathbb E(S_N\mid N=n)=\mathbb E(S_n)$, as without it you just have $\mathbb E(S_N\mid N=n)=\mathbb E(S_n\mid N=n)$.

For a counter example, we can take the $X_n$'s to be fair coin tosses, i.e. $\mathbb P(X_n=1)=\mathbb P(X_n=0)=1/2$, and then take $N=X_1$. Then of course $\mu=\mathbb E(N)=\mathbb E(X_1)=1/2$, but $\mathbb E(S_N)=\mathbb E(S_{X_1})=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

By the law of total expectation,the general formula is given by

$$\color{blue}{E[S_N] = E[N \,E[X | N]]},$$

with $X_i \sim X, i=1,2,\dots .$ This can be simplified to

$$E[S_N] = E[N]\mu,$$

when $N$ and $X$ are independent as $E[X | N]= E[X]=\mu$.